# registration form - browser is taking the wrong field as username

Tags: html, forms

I have a registration form made by the following fields (extract from the code):

```
<form role="form" id="profile_form" class="contact-form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="mail" class="input-box form-control" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="input-box form-control" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="cognome" class="input-box form-control" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="password" name="verify_password" placeholder="Verifica password" class="input-box form-control" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Firefox is considering `cognome` field to be the username holder and so on form submitting it is asking to save the password as password (that's fine) and the cognome field as username.

What am I doing wrong here? How am I going to tell firefox to take the email as username?

Comment: Consider swapping the `mail` input field with the `cognome` input field.

Comment: @user12137152 how is this comment going to answer my question?

Comment: I am not sure but what I have noticed is that firefox makes the input field just above the first occurrence of a password field as the username.